# LaTeX package error: Conflict between siunitx rounding precision and hyperref

Tags: tables, hyperref, siunitx

I want to round numbers in my tables and have content for my document. However, when I typeset the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\sisetup{round-mode      = places,
         round-precision = 3,
         group-separator = {,}}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\global\let\currentprecision\relax}}
\newcolumntype{^}{>{\ifthenelse{\isequivalentto{\currentprecision}{\relax}}{}{\currentprecision}}}
\newcommand{\rowprecision}[1]{\gdef\currentprecision{\sisetup{round-precision=#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{Pl*{2}{^S}}
    & A & B \\
\rowprecision{4} Row 1 & 3.22222 & 5.66666   \\
Row 2 & 1.44444 & 9.99999   \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

No PDF was produced and I got the error

```
Argument of \__siunitx_table_collect_not_braced:N has an extra }.
```

If I do not load the package `hyperref` then it works.

How could I solve the problem?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Your table is likely to look odd ... however, what I'm not sure is why you have the rather complicated code instead of just inserting `\currentprecision` unconditionally (as it is either a do-nothing or safe setting).

Comment: @JosephWright Because I need different precisions for different rows. So it's better to have a flexible one.  But the problem still occurs even if I remove the line `\newcommand{\rowprecision}[1]`

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you!

Comment: @Laika I still don't understand why you want to _test_ the nature of `\currentprecision` : is there more to your real use case?

Comment: @JosephWright Yes, `\currentprecision`  is a default one and can be universally applied to the whole table. But it's not enough for me.